# SQL date formatting sorting issue

Tags: sql

I've SQL query something like this.

```
select to_char(date_of_service, 'Mon-YY') as dos
from cases
```

I'm getting results something like this.

```
Oct-22
Jun-23
Apr-20
Jan-23
```

I want these results of be sorted by year and month wise, something like this.

```
Jan-23
Jun-23
Oct-22
Apr-20
```

Comment: For your Informatin. There is no intrinsic order to a relational database table. The only way to get a selection ordered is to use the `ORDER BY` syntax

Comment: PS I assume you are not using both MySQL and Postgress? So please only TAG the relevant database in future

Comment: SO you want the month sorted ASCending and the year sorted DESCending

Answer (score 2):

By sorting the dates in descending order, you'll get the results sorted by year and month wise, as shown in your desired output.

```
SELECT to_char(date_of_service, 'Mon-YY') AS dos
FROM cases
ORDER BY date_of_service DESC;
```

[ORDER BY](https://%20https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/cl%C3%A1usula-order-by-e8ea47f7-5388-460a-bec8-dcc81792d762) Clause

Comment: I would check the question again! Look at the requested order, its not `ORDER BY date_of_service DESC;` although that may have been a typo

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice the typo. Let's see what OP has to say.

Comment: @chetanKalore is it what you needed? is there a typo in your data sample? If not, provide the exact rule and more samples